# Performance in C#: Querying DataTable or XDocument with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datatable

I have quite a few datatables that are transported between processes by converting them to XML.

My question is, is it quicker to read the XML into a dataset / datatable on the other side and querying that (with LINQ) or should I just leave the XML and query with Linq?

Does the overhead in converting from XML to data table justify any search performance increases a data table may have?

The queries are mainly just finding a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of queries per table is small, then my guess is that it is faster to query the XML.  Reverse that advice if there are numerous queries.